How to lauch an android app from specific Fragment (activity)
I am doing automation testing of app using appium. And i need to launch app on specific page (activity)
but in my project there is only one RootActivity.
When I use this code on it works well but only for one and only activity.
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("mobile: startActivity", ImmutableMap.of("intent","com.kp.kompanion.debug/com.kp.kompanion.root.RootActivity"));
Is there any kind of way to implement launching specific Fragment?
